# What can be a possible reason for segmentation fault in this piece of code?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Basically, the following code takes as input `n` pairs, each of them having two parts, `a` and `b`. I sorted the entire vector using a custom comparator, which puts those values first that have a higher second value `(b)` and, if `b` is same, then those which have a higher `a` value. Here is the code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct mycomp
{
    bool operator() (const pair<int,int> &p1, const pair<int,int> &p2)
    {
        if (p1.second > p2.second)  // Here 
            return true;
        else if (p1.second == p2.second && p1.first >= p2.first)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};

int main (void)
{
    int i,n,a,b,foo;
    cin>>n;
    i = n;
    vector<pair<int,int> > myvec;
    while ( i != 0 )
    {
        cin>>a>>b;
        myvec.push_back(make_pair(a,b));
        i--;
    }
    int val = 0;
    sort(myvec.begin(),myvec.end(),mycomp());
    val = val + myvec[0].first;
    int k = myvec[0].second;
    foo = 1;
    while ( k!=0 && foo < n)   // This part basically calculates the values which I have to print. 
    {
        //k--;
        val = val + myvec[foo].first;
        k = k + myvec[foo].second;
        k--;
        foo++;
    }
    cout<<val<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

On executing this, with 100 as input, and the following being the pairs, it gives a seg fault. I tried running it through the debugger, and it says, 
`EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x101800004)` on line marked (Here) in code. What am I doing wrong in this?

Here is the link for the input file: `https://www.dropbox.com/s/79ygx4qo5qc8tsl/input.txt?dl=0`

Comment: Is `n > myvec.size()`?

Comment: @NathanOliver, nope. It's only `100`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function to compare the two pairs is faulty. If two of the pairs have the same `a` and `b`, `sort` will never complete.

Change it to:

```
struct mycomp
{
    bool operator() (const pair<int,int> &p1, const pair<int,int> &p2)
    {
       if ( p1.second != p2.second )
          return p1.second > p2.second;
       else
          return p1.first > p2.first;
    }
};
```

Comment: Your logic is completely correct, but I just have a small doubt, if `a` and `b` are equal of both the pairs, wont' it go to the condition 2? That is, `if (p1.second == p2.second && p1.first >= p2.first)`?

Comment: @JohnLui, I am assuming you are talking about your code. Yes, it will. The problem is that the function will return `true` even when the order of `p1` and `p2` is switched. `sort` does not work unless the compare function can guarantee strict ordering.

Comment: @JohnLui, your function should work if you use `if (p1.second == p2.second && p1.first > p2.first)`. Drop the `=` from `>=`.

Comment: Right, worked perfectly. Thanks for the clarification. Though I am fairly comfortable writing my own custom comparators now, but, I always face doubts in it. I just want to ask, what exactly does `return p1.second > p2.second` means? Since return type is `bool`, therefore, whenever `p1.second > p2.second` will be `true`, it will place `p1` before `p2`. Am I right in thinking this way? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the extended help. Much appreciated. :)